# Crear columnas booleanas en base a condición de iteración para una fecha

Tags: python, datetime, function, apply

Tengo un problema para automatizar un proceso, ya que no estoy logrando dar con la sintaxis correcta para una función.

El df de ejemplo está disponible [aquí](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/oblitterator/main/fall_prueba.csv). El mismo contiene listado de ID y fechas de fallecimiento asociadas a los mismos. Lo que deseo es obtener para distintas FECHA_FALLECIMIENTO una nueva columna para cada año señalado como fecha de corte (2019-30-06,2018-30-06,2017-30-06) con valores booleanos. Es decir, saber si determinado ID se encontraba fallecido a tal fecha según su FECHA_FALLECIMIENTO.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fecha_fallecido_prueba = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/oblitterator/main/fall_prueba.csv')
```

```
ID  FECHA_FALLECIDO
10000003    2015-06-21
10000007    2021-03-02
10000025    2009-09-19
10000183    2015-07-26
10000192    2016-07-31
10000193    2019-08-25
10000203    2018-05-16
10000222    2021-05-26
10000268    2018-12-08
10000273    2005-03-25
```

Si bien esto logro hacerlo para cada año en particular (por ejemplo para el año 2019, tomando como base el año 2020) con un boolean indexing:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

fecha_fallecido_prueba = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/oblitterator/main/fall_prueba.csv')

fecha_fallecido_prueba['FECHA_FALLECIDO'] = pd.to_datetime(fecha_fallecido_prueba['FECHA_FALLECIDO'])

fecha = pd.to_datetime('30/06/2020') #fecha base

anios = 1 #anios a mapear

fecha_fallecido_prueba['fall_2019'] = fecha_fallecido_prueba['FECHA_FALLECIDO'] <= (fecha - relativedelta(years=anios))
```

```
print(fecha_fallecido_prueba['fall_2019'])

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: fall_2019, dtype: bool
```

Lo que me gustaría saber es cómo realizar una función que itere y genere columnas según el número de años determinados. Es decir, poder obtener algo así para los años 2019,2018,2017 (anios = 3), por ejemplo.

```
         ID FECHA_FALLECIDO  fall_2017  fall_2018  fall_2019
0  10000003      2015-06-21       True       True       True
1  10000007      2021-03-02      False      False      False
2  10000025      2009-09-19       True       True       True
3  10000183      2015-07-26       True       True       True
4  10000192      2016-07-31       True       True       True
5  10000193      2019-08-25      False      False      False
6  10000203      2018-05-16      False       True       True
7  10000222      2021-05-26      False      False      False
8  10000268      2018-12-08      False      False       True
9  10000273      2005-03-25       True       True       True
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!! Espero que se haya entendido

Comment: Buen día, una pregunta, ¿Las fechas de corte que mencionas son para marcar las columnas de años como verdaderas? Es decir, si la fecha es 2018-07-01, ¿El resultado esperado sería False, False, True?

Comment: El link que pasaste retorna 404

Comment: Buenas! en realidad es para marcar las observaciones como verdaderas. Es decir, si la fecha de corte fuese 2018-30-06 para la primer observación sería True, True, True; para el segundo caso False False False, etc.

El ejemplo que puse final sería el resultado esperado, aunque ese lo hice aplicando un boolean indexing en cada caso.

Comment: Lo siento, sigo sin entender la fecha de corte, ¿Tiene que ver con algo de las columnas? Por lo que veo en las columnas si la persona fallece en el 2018 por ejemplo, ¿Sería False, False, True? ¿O es como lo expliqué en el comentario anterior?

Comment: Ahí edité la consulta y actualicé el link!

Mi intención es generar nuevas columnas (fall_2017, fall_2018, fall_2019) en base a mapear FECHA_FALLECIDO para cada ID, y que devuelva para cada observación True/False según las fechas de corte a iterar (en el ejemplo de arriba serían una comparación para 3 años). No sé si ahí quedó quizá más claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día

Podrías utilizar el método `date_range()` para generar los periodos de acuerdo a la fecha de corte y el número de años configurado

Luego puedes crear las columnas y asignarles los valores de `FECHA_FALLECIDO` dentro de un ciclo `for` y por último sustituir la fecha de fallecimiento con `True` o `False` para cada periodo dependiendo de la fecha de corte

Ejemplo (Los datos que utilicé son los que pusiste en tu pregunta, los pegué en un archivo csv):

```
import pandas as pd

#Obtenemos los datos y generamos el dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['FECHA_FALLECIDO'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_FALLECIDO'])

#Fecha base y periodo
fecha = pd.to_datetime('2020-06-15')
anios = 3

#Generamos los periodos deseados
periodos = pd.date_range(end=fecha, periods=anios, freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))

#Generamos las columnas deseadas
for periodo in periodos:
    #Creamos el título de la columna y la creamos con el método assign()
    col = 'corte_' + str(periodo.year)
    #Copiamos la fecha de fallecido en las columnas
    kwargs = {col : lambda x: x['FECHA_FALLECIDO']}
    df = df.assign(**kwargs)
    
    #Sustituímos la fecha de fallecido con True o False dependiendo del periodo(Fecha de corte de la columna)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: 'True' if (x <= periodo) else 'False')
    
print(df)
```

Esto genera el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    ID          FECHA_FALLECIDO corte_2018  corte_2019  corte_2020
0   10000003    2015-06-21      True        True        True
1   10000007    2021-03-02      False       False       False
2   10000025    2009-09-19      True        True        True
3   10000183    2015-07-26      True        True        True
4   10000192    2016-07-31      True        True        True
5   10000193    2019-08-25      False       False       True
6   10000203    2018-05-16      True        True        True
7   10000222    2021-05-26      False       False       False
8   10000268    2018-12-08      False       True        True
9   10000273    2005-03-25      True        True        True
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!